# Command line arguments and `gets`

Tags: ruby

In the following script:

```
first, second, third = ARGV

puts "The oldest brothers name is #{first}"
puts "The middle brothers name is #{second}"
puts "The youngest brothers name is #{third}"

puts "What is your moms name?"
mom = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "What is your dads name?"
dad = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "In the my family there are three sons #{first}, #{second}, #{third}, and a mom named #{mom}, and a father named #{dad}"
```

I cannot accept user input using the `gets` command without the `$stdin`. I have to use `$stdin.gets` in order for this to work.

Why is that? What does the `ARGV` do that disables this? Is `$stdin` not included by default with the `gets` command?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It will work with reference to `ARGV` in the code and without using `$stdin` as long as you do not pass any argument when you call the script from the terminal.

Comment: It appears as though the script is meant to be called with 3 arguments, that list the names of 3 brothers. If those names happen to be files then 'gets' will read them, otherwise nothing.

Answer (score 2):

From the [gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) function documentation:

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

So, if you pass command line arguments to your ruby program, `gets` will no longer read from `$stdin` but instead from those files you passed.

Imagine we had a shorter example of your code in a file called `argv.rb`:

```
first, second = ARGV

input = gets.chomp

puts "First: #{first}, Second: #{second}, Input #{input}"
```

And we created the following files:

```
$ echo "Alex" > alex
$ echo "Bob" > bob
```

And we run our program like `ruby argv.rb alex bob`, the output would be:

```
First: alex, Second: bob, Input Alex
```

Note that the value of `input` is "Alex", because that was the contents of the first file 'alex'. If we were to call `gets` a second time, the value returned would be "Bob" because that's what's inside the next file, "bob".